# Manejo de 'una' como indefinido

Tags: gramática, pronombres, género

En el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas, se aclara que el pronombre indefinido **uno** puede ser usado por una mujer

> (...) si la mujer que habla no hace alusión directa a sí misma, sino que habla en términos generales, podrá usar el indefinido uno, aludiendo al ser humano en general; así, podría ponerse en boca de una mujer una frase como *En este mundo en que vivimos, uno ya no sabe a qué atenerse.*

Por otro lado, puede verse 'persona' como sinónimo de 'ser humano', así pues la frase de ejemplo quedaría *una (persona) ya no sabe a que atenerse*. Si bien parece válido (aunque muy poco común), ¿Puede hacerse el cambio entre los pronombres teniendo en cuenta los géneros de 'ser humano' (m) y 'persona' (f)?

Comment: Como lo ha aclarado la rae en cientos de twits, se usa el "masculino gramatical" para incluir ambos géneros y así no toca adivinar si se esta hablando de "personas"  o de "humanos".  [Esta institución no avala el llamado «lenguaje inclusivo», que rechaza el valor genérico del masculino gramatical y altera artificialmente el funcionamiento de la morfología de género en español.](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/1111573363586203648?lang=en)

Comment: ¿No son los humanos y las personas la misma cosa?

Comment: La concordancia gramatical una(f)->persona(f) se da entre adjetivo y sustantivo. Pero en el ejemplo propuesto "una" y "uno" son pronombres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta afirmación del DPD:

> (...) si la mujer que habla no hace alusión directa a sí misma, sino que habla en términos generales, podrá usar el indefinido *uno*, aludiendo al ser humano en general; así, podría ponerse en boca de una mujer una frase como *En este mundo en que vivimos, uno ya no sabe a qué atenerse.*

no me parece muy feliz, o al menos está incompleta.

Cuando una mujer se refiere a todas las mujeres, usará "una", y en general usará el femenino en cualquier caso:

- **Una** a veces no sabe cómo actuar.

Es raro que una mujer use "uno" en forma genérica.

Comment: I agree with your answer but I invite you to use some other example that doesn't involve violence against women.